# How can I split a string into an array of substrings with regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to break a string of binary ones and zeros into groups of four. After reading the manual and the posts I am missing something:

```
$subject = "101010101";

$pattern = "/.{1,4}/";

$blocks = preg_split ($pattern, $subject);

print_r($blocks);
```

The result is an empty array.

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)
php >
```

Comment: [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) uses the `regex` to identify the delimiter. You don't need `regex` for this job, [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is better because it is faster (and easier to understand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that result because you are matching 1 - 4 characters to split on. It will match all the characters in the string leaving nothing to display.

If you want to use a regex to break it up into groups of 4 (and the last one because there are 9 characters) you could use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and match only 0 or 1 using a character class instead of using a dot which will match any character except a newline.

```
[01]{1,4}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KUVC4O/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/FMmWK)

```
$subject = "101010101";
$pattern = "/[01]{1,4}/";
$blocks = preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1010
    [1] => 1010
    [2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) which will split your string into an array of strings of size *n*.

```php
$subject = "101010101";
$split = str_split($subject, 4);
print_r($split);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1010
    [1] => 1010
    [2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

[**preg_split()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) returns an array containing substrings of subject split along boundaries matched by pattern, or FALSE on failure.. But you are trying to grab 1-4 characters group from that string. So [**preg_match_all()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) can be used for this purpose. [**Example**](https://3v4l.org/FIlDn):

```
$subject = "101010101";
$pattern = "/[01]{1,4}/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $match);

echo '<pre>', print_r($match[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any char in a string match your pattern, in other words, any string contains only delimiters. And result contains zero-sized spaces.

The get expected result you need capture only delimiters. You can do that adding two flags

```
$blocks = preg_split ($pattern, $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83032aaeb6a27fa19e49d7aa3a278351bf412f6e)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to get captured pattern in output

> If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern
>   will be captured and returned as well.  [`PHP reference`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

***Note:-*** You need to add the pattern into capturing group () to get it in ouput

---

```
$subject = "101010101";

$pattern = "/(.{1,4})/";

$blocks = preg_split ($pattern, $subject, null,  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($blocks);
```